# Tem como otimizar este código?

Tags: php, otimização, preg-match

Tem como otimizar esse código para deixá-lo mais rápido?

```php
if (strpos($qt, "blood") !== FALSE){
  if (preg_match("/^blood (?<blood>.+)$/", $qt, $match)){
    switch ($match['blood']) {
      case "a+": 
        $result = "A+"; 
        $sndline = "Ideal donor: A+<br>Other donors: A+ or O+<br>Only if no Rh(+) found: A- or O-"; 
        break;
      case "a-": 
        $result = "A-"; 
        $sndline = "Ideal donor: A-<br>Other donors: A- or O-"; 
        break;
      case "b+": 
        $result = "B+"; 
        $sndline = "Ideal donor: B+<br>Other donors: B+ or O+<br>Only if no Rh(+) found: B- or O-"; 
        break;
      case "b-": 
        $result = "B-";
        $sndline = "Ideal donor: B-<br>Other donors: B- or O-"; 
        break;
      case "ab+": 
        $result = "AB+"; 
        $sndline = "Ideal donor: AB+<br>Other donors: AB+ or A+ or B+ or O+<br>Only if no Rh(+) found: AB- or A- or B- or O-"; 
        break;
      case "ab-": 
        $result = "AB-"; 
        $sndline = "Ideal donor: AB-<br>Other donors: AB- or A- or B- or O-"; 
        break;
      case "o-": 
        $result = "O-"; 
        $sndline = "Ideal donor: O-<br>Other donors: O-"; 
        break;
      case "o+": 
        $result = "O+"; 
        $sndline = "Ideal donor: O+<br>Other donors: O+<br>Only if no Rh(+) found: O-"; 
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual o objetivo desse código? que conteúdo há na variável `$qt`? *letras, números, caracteres especiais*, etc.

Comment: vc ja ouviu falar em padroes de projeto? pensou em criar uma factory?

Comment: @qmechanik A variável `$qt` pode receber tudo isso que você disse, mas neste caso, ela recebe o texto: `blood a+`.

Comment: @IsraelZebulon Nunca ouvi falar sobre isso (sou ainda novo no PHP). Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: @hsbpedro A variável ´qt` pode vir nesse formato `texto_blooda+_outrotextobla`, sem espaços? ou sempre haverá espaços?

Comment: @qmechanik O que eu estou criando é um interpretador de textos. Neste caso, quero que quando o usuário digitar `blood <...>`, o interpretador pegue o que está no grupo `...` e imprima a mensagem em questão.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma de otimizar este código é eliminar o uso de *expressões regulares*, pois envolve o processo de implantar o motor do *regex* na *string*, o que causa uma [*sobrecarga*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_%28computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29), a não ser que seja realmente necessário usá-la, aliás, a página do PHP da [função `preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php), menciona:

> Não use `preg_match()` se você quiser somente verificar se uma *string*
>   aparece em outra *string*. Use `strpos()` ou `strstr()` em vez, eles
>   vão ser mais rápido.

Uma forma de fazer isto é usar a [função `strpos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) para encontrar a posição de um valor na *string* e com a [função `substr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php), extraí-la:

```php
function extrairPedaco($texto, $inicio, $delimitador){
    $sub = substr($texto, strpos($texto, $inicio) + strlen($inicio), strlen($texto));
    return substr($sub, 1, strpos($sub, $delimitador));
}
```

E para utilizá-la, faça assim:

```php
$texto = "The blood A+ tend to be cooperative, sensitive, clever, passionate and smart.";
$referencia = "blood";
$tipos = ['+', '-'];

foreach ($tipos as $tipo){
    $pedaco = extrairPedaco($texto, $referencia, $tipo);
    $pedaco = strtoupper($pedaco); // Converte para maiúsculo, eliminando a necessidade de usar a variável "result".
        switch($pedaco){
            case "A+": 
                echo "Ideal donor: A+<br>Other donors: A+ or O+<br>Only if no Rh(+) found: A- or O-"; 
                break;
            case "A-":  
                echo "Ideal donor: A-<br>Other donors: A- or O-"; 
                break;
            case "B+":  
                echo "Ideal donor: B+<br>Other donors: B+ or O+<br>Only if no Rh(+) found: B- or O-"; 
                break;
            case "B-":  
                echo "Ideal donor: B-<br>Other donors: B- or O-"; 
                break;
            case "AB+": 
                echo "Ideal donor: AB+<br>Other donors: AB+ or A+ or B+ or O+<br>Only if no Rh(+) found: AB- or A- or B- or O-"; break;
            case "AB-": 
                echo "Ideal donor: AB-<br>Other donors: AB- or A- or B- or O-"; 
                break;
            case "O-":  
                echo "Ideal donor: O-<br>Other donors: O-"; 
                break;
            case "O+":  
                echo "Ideal donor: O+<br>Other donors: O+<br>Only if no Rh(+) found: O-"; 
                break;
            default:
                // Faça algo aqui caso as comparações acima falhem.
                echo "No blood found\n";
                break;
        } 
}
```

### [`Exemplo`](http://ideone.com/4DF0to)

Comment: Valeu, Qmechanik!

Comment: não precisa do `!empty($pedaco)` pois irá cair no `default` do switch e `"Ideal donor: "` repete em todas sentenças poderia ser inicializado antes do switch e concatenado usando `$sndline .= '...';`

Comment: @GabrielGartz Obrigado pela sugestão.